# MVP, слой models

Tags: java, android, mvp

Такой вопрос по поводу `MVP`, а именно хочу уточнить по поводу слоя `models`, если класс является объектом структуры БД, и в нем никакой другой бизнес логики, можно ли его считать `model`?

Пример класса:

```
public class User extends RealmObject {

    @SerializedName("username")
    String username;
    @SerializedName("name")
    String name;
    @SerializedName("email")
    String email;
    @SerializedName("properties")
    private Properties properties;
    @SerializedName("password")
    String password;

    public User(String username, String name, String email, Properties properties) {
        this.username = username;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    public User() {

    }

    public User(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }


    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Properties getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }

    public void setProperties(Properties properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return username + " (" + name + ")";
    }

}
```

Comment: Конечно. Потому что: Модель (англ. Model) — предоставляет данные для пользовательского интерфейса. Т.е. все что представляет собой некие описанные данные - может являтся моделью

Comment: в MVP - model это более широкое структурное понятие, чем просто Realm POJO Object. Я наверное не соглашусь с ответом, потому что Model должно предоставлять данные а не быть её структурой. Те вы показываетет только структуру одного класса в БД, а по логике MVP у вас должна быть вся БД, более того несколько БД в одной MVP Model. Это как 1 Table в SQLIte он не может быть Model в MVP ну никак. Сама модель может состоять из одной БД, но никак не наоборот

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, безусловно это модель данных. ORM (к которым относится и Realm) вообще специально [для того и задумывалось](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ORM), чтобы совместить возможности СУБД и CRUD-операции с удобным для ООП форматом хранения данных (объекты-модели)

Comment: CRUD я думаю вы хотели написать

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei да, конечно